# Merging on closest value in SAS

Tags: sas, fuzzy-comparison

Is there a way in SAS to do a fuzzy *left* merge based on a numeric field? Say I have the two tables below and want to merge on the closest value possible.

Dataset A:

```
id_1    label
1       a
2       b
3       c
4       d
6       e
```

Dataset B:

```
id_2    
1.1     
2.9     
3.4     
4.05   
5.1
```

The result should be:

```
id_2    id_1    label
1.1     1       a
2.9     3       c
3.4     3       c
4.05    4       d
5.1     6       e
```

Please note that rounding isn't an option here because of the 5.1 case.

Comment: Technically `2.9` is closer to `3` then `3.4` is.  So your result table doesn't match the description for label `C`.

Comment: Also, `2.9` and `1.1` are equidistant from `2`, so which of those values should actually be chosen for `B`?

Comment: @RobertPenridge Both 2.9 and 3.4 match to 3 because those are the closest options in Dataset A.

Comment: @RobertPenridge 1.1 is closest to 1, so it matches with 1. 2.9 is closest to 3, so it matches with 3.

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  Label `b` has a value of 2.  Both 1.1 and 2.9 are 0.9 away, so which one should be chosen?

Comment: @RobertPenridge Sorry, I'm thinking of this as a left merge. Added that to the summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, SQL cartesian join.  This is not terribly fast, so it wouldn't be a good solution with large datasets.

```
data have_a;
input id_1    label $;
datalines;
1       a
2       b
3       c
4       d
6       e
;;;;
run;

data have_b;
input id_2 ;
datalines; 
1.1     
2.9     
3.4     
4.05   
5.1
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as
    select B.id_2, A.label , abs(A.id_1-B.id_2) as id_dist
    from have_a A, have_b B
    group by B.id_2
    having id_dist=min(id_dist);
quit;
```

Other solutions can be built depending on size of each dataset (are both very large, is one large and one small, or are both small).  PROC FORMAT returns a nice result, for example.

```
data have_a_fmt;
retain fmtname 'HAVE_AF';
set have_a(rename=(id_1=startpoint label=startlabel));
set have_a(firstobs=2);
set have_a(firstobs=3 rename=(id_1=endpoint label=endlabel)) end=eof;
start=id_1-(id_1-startpoint)/2;
end  =id_1+(endpoint-id_1)/2;
output;

if _n_=1 then do;
  hlo='l';
  end=start;
  start=.;
  label=startlabel;
  output;
end;
if eof then do;
  start=end;
  end=.;
  hlo='h';
  label=endlabel;
  output;
end;
run;

proc format cntlin=have_a_Fmt;
quit;

data want;
set have_b;
label=put(id_2,HAVE_AF.);
run;
```

Format solution is very fast unless have_A is very large (millions+). It works by doing a look-ahead and look-behind merge (using set, but same concept) to get 3 values at once, previous current and next, using them to define the ranges, and also adding first and last rows with 'low' and 'high' values for 'hlo' variable (which define 'negative infinity' and 'positive infinity' as endpoints in the ranges, basically).

Comment: This could return ties, by the way, you'd have to do something to fuzz the result to avoid ties (add a tiny random number perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with but it may need slight modifications based on clarifications to the question:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table final as
  select a.label,
         b.id_2
  from havea a
  join haveb b on 1 = 1
  left join haveb c on abs(c.id_2 - a.id_1) < abs(b.id_2 - a.id_1)
  where c.id_2 eq .
  ;
quit;
```

It's similar to Joe's in that it uses a cartesian join (joining on 1=1), but it is different in that it's not using a group-by statement.

It works by joining to table `haveb` a second time to see if it can find an even smaller difference in values.  If it can't then we know we have the smallest row, and we keep just those rows by applying a filter in the where clause.

Not sure if there's any performance difference or not.  I think Joe's `having` approach is easier to read/understand so I'd go with that.

Answer (score 0):

This can conceptually be much faster, although it does require the data to be sorted first...

no lookups, just a step-by-step linear merge.

You will need 3 SET statements for this to work (one for the current data, and two for consecutive records in your lookup). Then:

Do until (ran out of data)

1. if you ran out of lookups, set the last one to infinity (or otherwise invalidate it)
2. If the first lookup record is closer than the second, use it and move on to the next data point, keeping the same lookup records
3. Otherwise, advance both lookup records one step, keepin the same data record

end

depending on whether you want to keep ties or not, make the check in step 2 as < or <=, or add additional logic to handle them in some other way.